# How do I make powershell search a Word document for wildcards and return the word it found?

Tags: powershell

I am searching a very large amount of Word documents (5000) for a very large number of strings (3000).  I know how to do this in a Powershell script, but it takes an extremely long time.  Fortunately, most of these strings have common text in the first 3 or 4 characters, and I am able to narrow the strings down to roughly 300 if utilize wildcard searches in a find.execute statement.  If I search for (cod)* in strings.txt, and it find results such as "code," "coding", "coded", etc. in the Word doc, I need to have those results placed into a text file.  However, I'm not having much luck.

```
$filePath = "C:\files\"
$textPath = "C:\strings.txt"
$outputPath = "C:\output.txt"
$findTexts = (Get-Content $textPath)
$docs = Get-childitem -path $filePath -Recurse -Include *.docx 
$application = New-Object -comobject word.application 
Foreach ($doc in $docs)
{
   $document = $application.documents.open("$doc", $false, $true)
   $application.visible = $False
   $matchCase = $false 
   $matchWholeWord = $false 
   $matchWildCards = $true 
   $matchSoundsLike = $false 
   $matchAllWordForms = $false 
   $forward = $true 
   $wrap = 1
   $range = $document.content
   $null = $range.movestart()

   Foreach ($findtext in $findTexts)
   {
       $wordFound = $range.find.execute($findText,$matchCase,$matchWholeWord,$matchWildCards,$matchSoundsLike, $matchAllWordForms,$forward,$wrap) 
       if ($wordFound) 
       { 
           $docName = $doc.Name
           #Output search results and file name to a tab-delimited file
           "$findText`t$docName" | Out-File -append $outputPath   
        } #end if $wordFound 

     } #end foreach $findText
$document.close()
} #end foreach $doc
$application.quit()
```

If I have a Word doc with the word "coding" in it, this script results in output.txt containing the (cod)* wildcard and the filename because $findText = (cod)*.  So is there any way to get the word "coding" to output to the file?

Comment: You may find that the [OpenXML SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33292003/712649) will solve this type of task way faster than `Word.Application`

Comment: I have considered that, but my company is adamant about us not installing anything additional like that SDK.  If that's the only solution, I'll push them to make an exception, but I was hoping there might be a way to utilize Word.Application .  I did try to make this run as efficiently as possible by opening up the Word doc once, then searching the 3000 strings before closing it.  It helped, but it is still taking a long time.

Comment: If it helps, the entire SDK is comprised in one static dll + an XML manifest, no need to install or register anything on the machine.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I was able to obtain it, so this could be another great option to try in addition to the regex option from Dave.  Do you know how it would be coded?

Comment: That's actually exactly what my answer to the other question does :P (notice it uses `-match` in the inner keyword loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Word's wildcard searching why not just use a Powershell regex on all of the text in the document. Something like this:

```
if ($document.Content.Text -match "\b$($findText)\w+\b") 
{ 
  $docName = $doc.Name
  "$($matches[0])`t$docName" | Out-File -append $outputPath   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  This worked perfectly.  I had originally stuck with using Word methods in order to open the document as read-only because many of the documents can have comments in them, and if it's not opened in read-only mode, it halts with a dialog box about the doc having comments.  Since I opened it with a Word method, I thought I would do the find with a Word method as well.  But your solution combined the best of both, and it's working great.  Thank you!

Comment: This works great, however it only seems to return the first match found. Is there a way to have it list all matches?