# Find all ocurrence of wildcard in a Microsoft Word document with PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, ms-word, wildcard

I need to get all the ocurrences of a wildcard with regexp in a Microsoft Word document with powershell.

I found this solution, but only get the first ocurrence of the wildcard.

"How do I make powershell search a Word document for wildcards and return the word it found?"
[How do I make powershell search a Word document for wildcards and return the word it found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666586/how-do-i-make-powershell-search-a-word-document-for-wildcards-and-return-the-wor)

Can you help me.

Comment: See [PowerShell RegEx match all possible matches](//stackoverflow.com/a/33967205)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make powershell search a Word document for wildcards and return the word it found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666586/how-do-i-make-powershell-search-a-word-document-for-wildcards-and-return-the-wor)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use the code of the related issue with a little changes.
In the loop that search the different wildcards (**$finTest**) in the Content of the Word Document, I use a temporary content (**$tempContent**) initialized with (**$document.Content.Text**) value, then for every wildcard that I find in the file, I remove them from de temporary content and repeat (while) the process while the wildcard (regexp) been founded.

```
$filePath = "C:\files\"
$textPath = "C:\strings.txt"
$outputPath = "C:\output.txt"
$findTexts = (Get-Content $textPath)
$docs = Get-childitem -path $filePath -Recurse -Include *.docx 
$application = New-Object -comobject word.application 
Foreach ($doc in $docs)
{
   $document = $application.documents.open("$doc", $false, $true)
   $application.visible = $False
   $matchCase = $false 
   $matchWholeWord = $false 
   $matchWildCards = $true 
   $matchSoundsLike = $false 
   $matchAllWordForms = $false 
   $forward = $true 
   $wrap = 1
   $range = $document.content
   $null = $range.movestart()

   Foreach ($findtext in $findTexts)
   {
        #Set tempContent with de Content of the document
        $tempContent=$document.Content.Text
        while ($tempContent -match "\b$($findText)\w+\b") 
        { 
            #Remove all de ocurrences of wildcard founded, for the tempContent
            $tempContent=$tempContent -replace $matches[0],''
            $docName = $doc.Name
            "$($matches[0])`t$docName" | Out-File -append $outputPath   
        }

     } #end foreach $findText
$document.close()
} #end foreach $doc
$application.quit()
```