# Powershell script to return search results from a list of keywords

Tags: powershell, full-text-search

I have a project name called 'SFO104' and I have a list of serial numbers i.e 5011849, 5011850 etc and I have to search a long list of 500+ serial numbers to see if they exist in any other documents not relating to the project name **SFO104** or the PO number **114786**.

I was thinking of outputting the search results to a csv for  each serial number searched but the below isnt working.

```
$searchWords = gc C:\Users\david.craven\Documents\list.txt 
$results = @()
Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    $files = gci -path C:\Users\david.craven\Dropbox\ -filter "*$sw*" -recurse | select FullName

    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $object = New-Object System.Object
        $object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty –Name SearchWord –Value $sw
        $object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty –Name FoundFile –Value $file
        $results += $object
    }

}

$results | Export-Csv C:\Users\david.craven\Documents\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The image below shows my search of the serial number **5011849** and the results returned correspond to project **SFO104** which is as expected.

[image]

Comment: I'd start with the [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) Documentation

Comment: I added my code. Any thoughts as to why it isnt working?

Comment: Please edit the question and explain how come it doesn't work. What happens? Nothing, wrong results, something else?

Comment: Yes correct, there are no results. The csv file is 0KB.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works, the file is getting populated. However, what you have specified does not have the headers defined as in your screen shot. Also, what does that list.txt look like. My searchlist.txt is a single column file:

```
Hello
client
```

Using your code as is, only changing the file path and name, and a slight modification to where the filename is accessed, gives these results...

```
$searchWords = gc 'D:\Scripts\searchlist.txt' 
$results = @()
Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    $files = gci -path d:\temp -filter "*$sw*" -recurse

    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $object = New-Object System.Object
        $object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty –Name SearchWord –Value $sw
        $object | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty –Name FoundFile –Value $file.FullName
        $results += $object
    }

}

$results | Export-Csv d:\temp\searchresults.csv -NoTypeInformation


# Results
# psEdit -filenames 'd:\temp\searchresults.csv'

SearchWord FoundFile
---------- ---------
Hello      D:\temp\Duplicates\PowerShellOutput.txt
Hello      D:\temp\Duplicates\BeforeRename1\PowerShellOutput.txt
Hello      D:\temp\Duplicates\PoSH\PowerShellOutput.txt
Hello      D:\temp\Duplicates\Text\PowerShellOutput.txt
client     D:\temp\Client.txt
client     D:\temp\Duplicates\CertLabClients_v1.ps1
client     D:\temp\Duplicates\Check Logon Server for Client.ps1
client     D:\temp\Duplicates\Create Wireless Hosted Networks in Windows Clients.ps1
...
```

***Update for OP***

Since you are using a comma separate list. You need to break that into separate items. I changed my file to this

```
Hello,client
```

You cannot match on that layout unless you are trying to match the whole consecutive string. So, if I break the above this way ...

```
$searchWords = (gc 'D:\Scripts\searchlist.txt') -split ','
```

… thus the results are as shown before.

***Update for the OP***

Example, test with this (a different rough approach)...

```
Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    Get-Childitem -Path "d:\temp" -Recurse -include "*.txt","*.csv" | 
    Select-String -Pattern "$sw" | 
    Select Path,LineNumber,@{n='SearchWord';e={$sw}}
}
```

The LineNumber was sonly added so show where the string was located. Also, note, your code, and what I provide here, will only work for text, csv files.

If you plan to hit these, doc, docx, xls, xlsx, that means way more code as you have to use the default apps Word, Excel, to open and read these files.

This means using the COM Object model for each of those file types in your code. As discussed and shown here:

[How do I make powershell search a Word document for wildcards and return the word it found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666586/how-do-i-make-powershell-search-a-word-document-for-wildcards-and-return-the-wor)

You'd need to do a similar thing for Excel or PowerPoint, and if you have PDF, that requires and addon.

***Update for OP***

Like I said, I put this together quickly so it is a bit rough (no error handling, etc...) by I did test it using my input file and target folder tree and it does work.

```
# This is what my input looks like
Hello,client
595959, 464646 
LIC
```

Running the code should have given you the results below, using only *.txt,*.csv files. Using any other file type will error by design as per my comment above regarding, you cannot use this approach for non text-based files without using the native app for the non text file type.

```
$searchWords = ((gc 'D:\Scripts\searchlist.txt') -split ',').Trim()

Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    Get-Childitem -Path "d:\temp" -Recurse -include "*.txt","*.csv" | 
    Select-String -Pattern "$sw" | 
    Select Path,LineNumber,@{n='SearchWord';e={$sw}}
}

Path                                            LineNumber SearchWord
----                                            ---------- ----------
D:\temp\Duplicates\BeforeRename1\PsGet.txt             157 Hello     
...    
D:\temp\Duplicates\PoSH\PsGet.txt                      157 Hello     
...   
D:\temp\Duplicates\BeforeRename1\PoSH-Get-Mo...        108 client    
D:\temp\Duplicates\BeforeRename1\Powershell ...         12 client    
D:\temp\Duplicates\BeforeRename1\Powershell ...         15 client    
D:\temp\Duplicates\BeforeRename1\PsGet.txt             454 client    
...
D:\temp\newfile.txt                                      4 client    
D:\temp\MyFile.txt                                       5 595959    
D:\temp\ProcessNames.csv                                 4 595959    
D:\temp\Duplicates\Text\JSON-CSS.txt                    30 464646    
D:\temp\Duplicates\JSON-CSS.txt                         30 464646    
D:\temp\MyFile.txt                                       5 464646    
D:\temp\ProcessNames.csv                                 4 464646    
D:\temp\Duplicates\BeforeRename1\GetSetScree...          7 LIC
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Its not working for me as when I run it my file is 0KB.

Comment: Sorry to clarify I want the searchlist.txt to contain a list of number values i.e 595959, 464646 which will be used to search file contents in a folder location which has multiple other folders and files across multiple file types such as doc, docx, csv, xls, xlsx, txt etc.

Comment: Ah, that is the reason I asked for the what's on that file. See my update for you.

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks, although the SearchWord doesn't show.

Comment: The script runs very very slow. It has yet to finish as I have cancelled it to do further testing. The longest run has been 20 minutes.The folder we are searching is 507 MB (532,369,408 bytes) and it contains 1,119 Files & 480 Folders. It

Comment: It will, due to  a couple of things. ForLoops are just inherently slow, and you have two of them and secondly, you are getting the files on each and every loop. Try the update I have for you.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time on this. I tried the above changed but received this error  `Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is an 
empty string.
At C:\Users\david.craven\Downloads\test.ps1:10 char:28
+     Select-String -Pattern "$sw" |
+                            ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindin 
   gValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAll 
   owed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
 
`