# Searching a large folder full of files with a list of keywords within a text document using PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, search, full-text-search, powershell-4.0

For example I have a text file with below keywords:

apple
ball
banana
yellow

How do I take this text file above, full of keywords to search a large folder over power-shell. Please note that I would like to find out the exact keyword where it is located and what is included within the line its included in, I'm not interested in the line number or file name it is located in.

Thanks for your support

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help Select-String` ... especially at `Get-Help Select-String -Parameter Context`.

Comment: Potential duplicate of... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105844/powershell-script-to-return-search-results-from-a-list-of-keywords/53109311#53109311

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yet...?