# Looking for a Wildcard String then Writing it to Output

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I recently began my Powershell journey and I have written code that will search a group of word documents for a keyword (or phrase) and export the document names to a txt file. Now I was wondering if I'd be able to search for a phrase, say for example: "wait * days", then output the full phrase "wait 10 days" to a txt file. The code I currently have is summarized briefly as:

I'd appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction or show me where to start in terms of writing this program. Thank you!

As you can see below, I have written pretty much all of the code for finding a keyword in a document. All I need is direction in terms of what function would allow me to write find the wildcard phrase to a txt file.

```
$keyword = 'SOMETHING'
$source = 'C:\somepath'

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*.doc*'}
{
    if ($word.Documents.Open($doc.FullName).Content.Find.Execute($keyword))
        {
        #Output Code
        }
    $word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
}
```

Currently, the code can open and read microsoft word documents and write the document to an output file. Though I'm hoping to write the results of the wildcard search into the output.
Obviously, Stack overflow is not about getting code written for you. So any direction or even letting me know if this is possible in powershell would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make powershell search a Word document for wildcards and return the word it found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666586/how-do-i-make-powershell-search-a-word-document-for-wildcards-and-return-the-wor)

Comment: @mhu that's using regex, but I'm hoping to use the word app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this is to pull the body and then use `-match` to find what you are looking for.

There is the `Find.MatchWildcards` property. However, I could not get it to work as expected.  [Find.MatchWildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.matchwildcards)

Example. Get string starting with "wait" and ending with "days":

```
#looking for wait X days
#regex for wildcard
$keyword = '(wait).*(days)'
$source = 'C:\somepath'

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $False

$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*.doc*'}

$results = @{}
foreach($doc in $docs)
{    
    #open read only
    $document = $word.Documents.Open($doc.FullName,$false,$True)
    $body = $document.content
    #use Regex
    if($body.Text -match "$keyword")
    {
        #Example of action write to file each time there is a match
        $Matches[0] | out-file "C:\IndividualMatch.txt" -Append
        $properties = @{
            File = $doc.FullName
            Match = $keyword
            CompleteMatch = $Matches[0]
        }
        #store to results
        $results += $properties
    }
    $word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()   

}
if($results)
{
    #if there are matches... do action -- output to text
    $results.CompleteMatch | Out-File "C:\test.txt"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Cant find"
}
#clean up com object
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Can't seem to write the results to a file or anything though.

Comment: @Lazed there are two areas you can take action if there is a match. After the `$body.Text -match`. You can output the matched string just using `$Matches[0] | out-file "C:\results.txt"` . And/Or, you can output after it is done searching be using: `$results.CompleteMatch | out-file "C:\results.txt"` . Solution updated to include it

Comment: alright one last question, if I wanted to search for "wait * day!", would that be entered as: '(wait).*(day)!'

Comment: @Lazed It would be `(wait).*(day!)` . Your way would work as well. Putting it in parentheses captures it as a group. I use [this site for Regex](https://regexr.com/) . It will allow you to test your Regex