# How can I modify this PowerShell script to continue looking for one string after another?

Tags: string, powershell, file, search, find

I want this power shell script to search for the occurrence of multiple strings, one after the other, and to append the results in a .txt file.

Currently I am specifying the string that I want to look for, waiting for the script to finish looking for that string and transferring the results into a spreadsheet. This is taking a lot of time as I have to keep specifying the string I want to look for, especially since there are well over 100 that I need to look for.

```
#ERROR REPORTING ALL
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$path = "C:\Users\username\Documents\FileName"
$files = Get-Childitem $path -Include *.docx,*.doc,*.ppt, *.xls, 
*.xlsx, *.pptx, *.eap -Recurse | Where-Object { !($_.psiscontainer) }
$output = 
"C:\Users\username\Documents\FileName\wordfiletry.txt"
$application = New-Object -comobject word.application
$application.visible = $False
$findtext = "First_String"

Function getStringMatch
{
  # Loop through all *.doc files in the $path directory
  Foreach ($file In $files)
  {
   $document = $application.documents.open($file.FullName,$false,$true)
   $range = $document.content
   $wordFound = $range.find.execute($findText)

   if($wordFound) 
    { 
     "$file.fullname has found the string called  $findText and it is 
$wordfound" | Out-File $output -Append
    }

  }
$document.close()
$application.quit()
}

getStringMatch
```

This script will look for 'First_String' successfully, I was hoping to be able to specify 'Second_String', 'Third_String' etc rather than replace First_String every time.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291871/optimize-word-document-keyword-search/33292003#33292003)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the suggestion from @Mathias, you could use Regex to query the document text instead.

Read the context of the document as a string `$text = $document.content.text` and then use `Select-String $findtext -AllMatches` to evaluate the matches with `$findtext` as string representation of a regular expression instead.

Example:

```
# pipe delimited string as a regular expression
$findtext = "First_String|Second_String|Third_String"

Function getStringMatch
{
  # Loop through all *.doc files in the $path directory
  Foreach ($file In $files)
  {
    $document = $application.documents.open($file.FullName,$false,$true)
    $text = $document.content.text
    $result = $text | Select-String $findtext -AllMatches

    if($result) 
    {
      "$file.fullname has found the strings called $($result.Matches.Value) at indexes $($result.Matches.Index)" | Out-File $output -Append
    }
  }

  $document.close()
  $application.quit()
}
```

Note that if you're trying find strings that do have reserved regex character, you'll need to escape them first